# Unable to attach debugger while running Azure Functions Locally, following this

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to develop Azure Functions Locally, following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code).

Everything is fine until the execution part where if click `Execute Function Now`, I only see following popup at bottom right corner.

[image]

Open trying to do it through meny `Run` > `Start Debugging (F5)`, I see below:

[image]

The `npm install (functions) Task` stays like this forever, and function is still not executing neither a debugger is attached.

At last writing `func host start` in the terminal does execute my functions and I can call it through the mentioned endpoint but without a debugger and no breakpoints being hit.

Can anybody help me with what am I doing wrong and how can I attached debugger while executing functions locally?

```
Core Tools Version:       4.0.3971 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.0.1.16815
```

Answer (score -1):

We have tried to reproduce the above issue but its working fine at our end .

we have to make sure that following tools are installed in our local.

- [***Node.js***](https://nodejs.org/en/) v16.13.0 (we have used this version as installed previously)
- [***Azure function core tools v4***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)
- [***VS CODE(extension AZURE FUNCTION)***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions)

Tried to create a sample ***Azure function (HTTP TRIGGER)*** using `javascript`
And try to debug it using `F5 debugger` and it runs perfectly. and using `func host start` cmd as well.

***OUTPUT DETAILS FOR REFERNCE:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information Please refer this ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***:- [***Create a JavaScript function in Azure using Visual Studio Code***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node)